# gzip в codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Как включить gzip в codeigniter?
есть в конфиге строчка

```
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;
```

Сменил на TRUE, но Page Speed в Хроме все равно говорит Включите Gzip. а про строчку эту прочитал на англ форуме,якобы она включает gzip

Comment: По-хорошему gzip нужно включать не в php а "этажом выше" в apache или nginx

Comment: У меня сайт на хостинге, какие мои следующие действия=)?

Comment: Ваши следующие действия, это письмо хостеру с просьбой включить gzip, если он не включен.

Answer (score 1):

Я тебе советую поставить [новую версию CI 3.0](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter), там появился ещё один хороший параметр -$config['minify_output'] = TRUE;